# I want to fire a specific function when the bool value becomes true

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to play the SE when `IsReceive=true`.

collider.cs

```
public class ParentSlimeWeaponCollider : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool IsReceive=false;
    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Weapon") || other.gameObject.CompareTag("MolotovCocktail"))
        {
           IsReceive=true;
        }
    }
}
```

playerSE.cs

```
public class SlimesReceiveSE : MonoBehaviour
{
[SerializeField] private AudioClip WeaponReceiveSE;
AudioSource audioSource;

private ParentSlimeWeaponCollider _parentSlimeWeaponCollider;

void Start()
{
    audioSource = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
}

void ReceiveSe()
{
    audioSource.PlayOneShot(WeaponReceiveSE);
}
}
```

Comment: What is the problem you're having?

Comment: Are you familiar with C# properties and events?

Comment: Making it a property its easy to do im with Joe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Weapon") || other.gameObject.CompareTag("MolotovCocktail"))
    {
       IsReceive=true;
       FindObjectOfType<SlimesReceiveSE>().ReceiveSe();
    }
}
```

and don't forgot to make ReceiveSe function public.

or you can check this IsRecieve bool in update and in SlimesReceiveSE script and when it is true called ReceiveSe.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 
'FindObjectOfType<SlimesReceiveSE>().ReceiveSe();' seems to be heavy processing, so I rewrote it to 'GetComponent<SlimesReceiveSe>().ReceiveSe();'.

Comment: if you have both scripts in same gameobject then you can use GetComponent otherwise FindObjectOfType